# I have a weird error on Sigil regarding my fonts

Tags: epub, fonts, sigil

I use three fonts in my ebook. Two of them Sigil is okay with. However, the primary font is kicking the weirdest error.

Every time I validate, Sigil gives me two errors for each member of the font family:

- The resource is reachable, but it's not in the OPF.
- The resource is in the OPF, but it's not reachable.

That's right. It complains about two entirely contradicting things. So does anyone have any clue what could generate an error like this?

FINAL EDIT: Ah, I managed to figure out the solution. So basically, the opf referenced the font as `Fonts/GoudyOldstyle-Regular.otf`, but my `@font-face` referenced `../Fonts/GoudyOldStyle-Regular.otf`. So basically the name was syntactically correct enough for the font to appear, but the capitalization confused the validator. As soon as I fixed the capitalization everything was bread like butter.

EDIT #1: Whoops. Put a 'not' in the wrong place. I fixed it. And yes, the filepaths check out. It works on my phone via Google Play Books, and it works when converted via Calibre to .awz3 format and plopped on a Kindle Fire. For some reason, it just has major grief about a problem that isn't there.

EDIT #2: I'm actually trying to upload the file through the IngramSpark program, and their validator is kicking a similar error, and will not allow me to progress. Here is the code in the opf file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" unique-identifier="BookId" version="2.0">
  <metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:opf="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf">
    <dc:identifier id="BookId" opf:scheme="ISBN">urn:isbn:978-0-9915595-0-3</dc:identifier>
    <dc:title>Baron Syndicate (-1): Crossroads of Destiny</dc:title>
    <dc:creator opf:file-as="Decker, Dennis L." opf:role="aut">Dennis L. Decker</dc:creator>
    <dc:language>en</dc:language>
    <dc:date opf:event="modification">2014-11-25</dc:date>
    <dc:identifier opf:scheme="ISBN">978-0-9915595-0-3</dc:identifier>
    <dc:contributor opf:file-as="Miller, Neil" opf:role="aut">Neil Miller</dc:contributor>
    <dc:contributor opf:file-as="Ritzo, Sean" opf:role="edt">Sean Ritzo</dc:contributor>
    <dc:contributor opf:file-as="Daufenbach, Uwe" opf:role="trl">Uwe Daufenbach</dc:contributor>
    <dc:contributor opf:file-as="Magtrayo, Paul Ritz" opf:role="ill">Paul Ritz Magtrayo</dc:contributor>
    <meta content="0.7.4" name="Sigil version" />
    <meta content="Cover.jpg" name="cover" />
    <dc:identifier opf:scheme="UUID">urn:uuid:5eec0b00-f905-45c3-857a-e2b89b0c0e4f</dc:identifier>
  </metadata>
  <manifest>
    <item href="toc.ncx" id="ncx" media-type="application/x-dtbncx+xml" />
    <item href="Text/chap01.xhtml" id="chap01.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item href="Fonts/DearKatieNBP_BS.ttf" id="DearKatieNBP_BS.ttf" media-type="application/x-font-ttf" />
    <item href="Fonts/Giorgio_Handwriting.otf" id="Giorgio_Handwriting.otf" media-type="application/vnd.ms-opentype" />
    <item href="Fonts/GoudyOldstyle-Bold.otf" id="GoudyOldstyle-Bold.otf" media-type="application/vnd.ms-opentype" />
    <item href="Fonts/GoudyOldstyle-Italic.otf" id="GoudyOldstyle-Italic.otf" media-type="application/vnd.ms-opentype" />
    <item href="Fonts/GoudyOldstyle-Regular.otf" id="GoudyOldstyle-Regular.otf" media-type="application/vnd.ms-opentype" />
    <item href="Styles/stylesheet.css" id="stylesheet.css" media-type="text/css" />
    <item href="Text/title.xhtml" id="title.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item href="Text/chap02.xhtml" id="chap02.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item href="Text/chap03.xhtml" id="chap03.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item href="Text/chap04.xhtml" id="chap04.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item href="Text/chap05.xhtml" id="chap05.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item href="Text/chap06.xhtml" id="chap06.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item href="Text/chap07.xhtml" id="chap07.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item href="Text/chap08.xhtml" id="chap08.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item href="Text/chap09.xhtml" id="chap09.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item href="Text/chap10.xhtml" id="chap10.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item href="Text/chap11.xhtml" id="chap11.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item href="Text/chap12.xhtml" id="chap12.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item href="Text/chap13.xhtml" id="chap13.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item href="Text/chap14.xhtml" id="chap14.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item href="Text/chap15.xhtml" id="chap15.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item href="Text/afterD.xhtml" id="afterD.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item href="Text/afterN.xhtml" id="afterN.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item href="Text/thanks.xhtml" id="thanks.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item href="Text/toc.xhtml" id="toc.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item href="Images/Cover.jpg" id="Cover.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg" />
    <item href="Text/cover.xhtml" id="cover.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item href="Text/dedication.xhtml" id="dedication.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item href="Text/copyright.xhtml" id="copyright.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
  </manifest>
  <spine toc="ncx">
    <itemref idref="cover.xhtml" />
    <itemref idref="title.xhtml" />
    <itemref idref="copyright.xhtml" />
    <itemref idref="dedication.xhtml" />
    <itemref idref="toc.xhtml" />
    <itemref idref="chap01.xhtml" />
    <itemref idref="chap02.xhtml" />
    <itemref idref="chap03.xhtml" />
    <itemref idref="chap04.xhtml" />
    <itemref idref="chap05.xhtml" />
    <itemref idref="chap06.xhtml" />
    <itemref idref="chap07.xhtml" />
    <itemref idref="chap08.xhtml" />
    <itemref idref="chap09.xhtml" />
    <itemref idref="chap10.xhtml" />
    <itemref idref="chap11.xhtml" />
    <itemref idref="chap12.xhtml" />
    <itemref idref="chap13.xhtml" />
    <itemref idref="chap14.xhtml" />
    <itemref idref="chap15.xhtml" />
    <itemref idref="afterD.xhtml" />
    <itemref idref="afterN.xhtml" />
    <itemref idref="thanks.xhtml" />
  </spine>
  <guide>
    <reference href="Text/cover.xhtml" title="Cover" type="cover" />
  </guide>
</package>
```

Comment: The sentences are worded differently but I don't see any contradiction. Have you checked filenames and paths?

Comment: I would try to validate it with another editor (i.e. Calibre includes one) and see if it shows up again; if not, maybe is just a problem with Sigil.

Comment: What does it show up in the .opf file as if you look at the .opf in a text editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting an edit from above.

> Ah, I managed to figure out the solution. So basically, the opf referenced the font as `Fonts/GoudyOldstyle-Regular.otf`, but my @font-face referenced `../Fonts/GoudyOldStyle-Regular.otf`. So basically the name was syntactically correct enough for the font to appear, but the capitalization confused the validator. As soon as I fixed the capitalization everything was bread like butter.

Comment: As this answer helped best to resolve your problem (even if it's your own answer) you should mark it as an accepted answer to help future visitors of the page.

Comment: Done. Thanks for that, I'm quite new to Stack Exchange. I'm very grateful for everyone's help.